# Proxy object - access target from within a getter property?

Tags: javascript

I have a simple proxy object:

```js
const myProxy = new Proxy(
  /* myTarget */
  {
    test: 2,
  },
  /* myHandler */
  {
    get(target, prop, proxy)
    {
      if (prop in this && this[prop] instanceof Function)
        return this[prop](target); //getter

      return target[prop]; //value
    },
    
    myGetter(target)
    {
      return ++target.test
    }
  }
);

console.log("test before", myProxy.test);
console.log("myGetter", myProxy.myGetter);
console.log("test after", myProxy.test);
```

Is there a way make `myGetter` property as a true getter?
My attempt failed, because I don't know how to access `myTarget` from within the getter:

```js
const myProxy = new Proxy(
  /* myTarget */
  {
    test: 2,
  },
  /* myHandler */
  {
    get(target, prop, proxy)
    {
      if (prop in this)
        return this[prop]; //getter

      return target[prop]; //value
    },
    
    get myGetter()
    {
      return ++target.test; //target undefined
    }
  }
);

console.log("test before", myProxy.test);
console.log("blah", myProxy.myGetter);
console.log("test after", myProxy.test);
```

The reason why I need this is because I have multiple functions inside the handler and I need to determine which one needs to be executed within handler itself (`myGetter`), or should be returned as function reference (`myFunc`), where it can also accept additional data as arguments, so I'm using `prop instanceof Function` to check if it's a function or not:

```js
const myProxy = new Proxy(
  /* myTarget */
  {
    test: 2,
  },
  /* myHandler */
  {
    get(target, prop, proxy)
    {
      if (prop in this)
      {
        if (this[prop] instanceof Function)
          return (args) => this[prop](target, args); //function

        return this[prop]; //getter
      }
      return target[prop]; //value
    },
    
    get myGetter()
    {
      return ++target.test; //target undefined
    },

    myFunc(target, value)
    {
      return target.test * value;
    }
  }
);

console.log("myFunc", myProxy.myFunc(3));
console.log("test before", myProxy.test);
console.log("myGetter", myProxy.myGetter);
console.log("test after", myProxy.test);
```

I could think of several work arounds, for example hard code names of functions:

```js
const myProxy = new Proxy(
  /* myTarget */
  {
    test: 2,
  },
  /* myHandler */
  {
    get(target, prop, proxy)
    {
      if (prop in this)
      {
        if (["myFunc"].includes(prop)) // function
          return (args) => this[prop](target, args);

        return this[prop](target); // getter
      }
      return target[prop];
    },
    
    myGetter(target)
    {
      return ++target.test
    },

    myFunc(target, value)
    {
      return target.test * value;
    }
  }
);

console.log("myFunc", myProxy.myFunc(3));
console.log("test before", myProxy.test);
console.log("myGetter", myProxy.myGetter);
console.log("test after", myProxy.test);
```

Or separate functions into groups:

```js
const myProxy = new Proxy(
  /* myTarget */
  {
    test: 2,
  },
  /* myHandler */
  {
    get(target, prop, proxy)
    {
      if (prop in this._myFuncs)
        return (args) => this._myFuncs[prop](target, args);

      if (prop in this._myGetters)
        return this._myGetters[prop](target);

      return target[prop];
    },
    
    _myGetters:
    {
      myGetter(target)
      {
        return ++target.test
      },
    },

    _myFuncs:
    {
      myFunc(target, value)
      {
        return target.test * value;
      },
    }
  }
);

console.log("myFunc", myProxy.myFunc(3));
console.log("test before", myProxy.test);
console.log("myGetter", myProxy.myGetter);
console.log("test after", myProxy.test);
```

For education purpose any suggestions how to make true getter to work in Proxy?

Comment: You need to define the getter on the target object of the proxy, not on the handler object. And also you should properly use `Reflect.get` to pass the receiver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the handler object should have nonstandard properties on it - it'd make more sense for it to only have the [traps that it's expected to have](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy#handler_functions). To have collection of properties for traps, either hard-code those properties (which is inflexible and not so nice) or use a separate object structure for those properties. With a separate object in the proxy closure, checking whether the property exists on the object and then `.call`ing it with target if it's a getter is easy.

```js
const makeProxy = (target, customProperties) => {
  return new Proxy(
    target, {
      get(target, prop, proxy) {
        if (prop in customProperties) {
          // Invoke getter if it exists on customProperties
          const { get } = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(customProperties, prop);
          if (get) {
            return get.call(target);
          }
        }
        // Otherwise return original object value or getter
        return target[prop];
      },
    }
  );
};

const proxy = makeProxy({
  test: 2,
}, {
  get myGetter() {
    return ++this.test
  }
});

console.log("test before", proxy.test);
console.log("blah", proxy.myGetter);
console.log("test after", proxy.test);
```

Comment: Thank you. The `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor` is what I was missing. It returns `get` property for getters and `value` for everything else.